# What's the difference between privateCloudOrderType?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have found the following description.
Do you have any information of these Type?

privateCloudOrderType
Type of Virtual Server (Private Node) order. Potential values: INITIAL, ADDHOST, ADDIPS, ADDZONE
Type: string

ContainerSoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest | SoftLayer Development Network - http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea, but I can tell you that property is not used for orders, if you want to order a private node you need to make sure that you are picking the price for a private node, for example this price:

```
itemPrice": {
                "hourlyRecurringFee": ".209",
                "recurringFee": "139",
                "item": {
                    "description": "Private 1 x 2.0 GHz Core"
                }
            }
```

So you need to make sure that the prices that you are picking are the correct for the server configuration that you desire.

Regards